# const char** and free()

Tags: c, visual-studio, malloc, free

I'm trying to free a table of pointers using Visual Studio 2013.

```
const char** tableNames = malloc(NB_NAMES * sizeof(char*));
(...)
free(tableNames);
```

For some reason, Visual keeps complaining :
`warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers`

I could understand this warning if it was about freeing a `const char*`, since this one could be a static read-only content.

But a `const char**` (notice the second `*`) ? This is a table of pointers. The table itself should be released, since it was malloc'd to begin with.

Is that a bug from Visual or am I missing something ?

*Note* : I can disable the warning, or shut it down by casting to `void*` inside the `free()`. But it doesn't sound that right if it's just a way to fool the compiler and remain exposed to some problem.

So the question really is : is that a compiler bug (and the cast to `void*` shouldn't be necessary) ?

Answer (score 3):

A `const char**` is still a pointer with a `const` qualifier, regardless of whether it points to a primitive type or to another pointer.  That's why the warning shows up.

In this case it's fine to cast the pointer when you call free.  For example:

```
free((void *)tableNames);
```

Or:

```
free((char **)tableNames);
```

Comment: It looks a bit strange : releasing the table of pointers (which are not `const`) doesn't mean releasing the memory used by the `const char*` strings. In fact, they are still there. So I'm not sure to understand why the `const` qualifier should be taken into consideration.